# Categorize/Tag projects in Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm

> Let me explain the big problem

Is there a way to apply categories/tags to a project in Dynamics CRM?

We wish to group sets of projects in categories. e.g.:

- **Client A** project
- **Client B** project
- **Client C** project
- and so on...

I've tried to [find possibilities](https://www.google.com/search?q=project+category+in+dynamics+crm) however there doesn't seems to be a nice solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It depends on what type of categorisation you are trying to do. If you are wanting to group by a defined list, that does not look likely to change then you could do this using an option set attribute. If the attribute does look like it will be updated often, then an entity lookup attribute to a custom entity would work better. If you are trying to group against a client then use a lookup to the clients account record

Comment: There are some pay for solutions out there that offer tagging, one I am intimately aware of due to helping develop it is tagging for CRM by xrmconsultancy (http://www.xrmconsultancy.com/what-we-do/tagging-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm/).

Comment: @StefanWilliam-Worrall you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what type of categorisation you are trying to do. If you are wanting to group by a defined list, that does not look likely to change then you could do this using an option set attribute. If the attribute does look like it will be updated often, then an entity lookup attribute to a custom entity would work better. If you are trying to group against a client then use a lookup to the clients account record

Comment: Is there a way to [categorize the notes as well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39995092/2404470)?

Comment: Notes don't make sense without the context of entity record they are about, so I would advise to search for your project based on the categorisation and link to the related notes as well. How you implement this depends on how you are loading the data

Comment: If we just wanted to have attachments in the project, is `Notes` the correct approach in the first place? Is there a way to have `Attachments` entity be associated with the `Project` entity and shown in the **Project form**?

Comment: If you do not have a Document Management System implemented then notes will be your only option. Notes are easily displayed on the form using the Note control / Social Pane