# How do we categorize/tag the notes in online Dynamics CRM?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm

> **Main target:** *have project documents files attached to projects and be able to categorize documents across multiple projects.
> e.g.: A,B,C... type documents may belong to x,y,z... projects*
>
> **Tentative target** : categorize/tag the notes and their attachments.

In the latest online Dynamics CRM, we've got the `Note` entity

[image: CRM notes entity]

For **categoriz/tagg-ing**, we've created a custom `Tagging` entity

[image: custom Tagging entity]

When we try to build any relationships, `Notes` is not made available

[image: notes not available in relationship mapping]

At a very high level - categorizing/tagging looks [feasible using a custom entity with relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39957676/2404470), but it doesn't looks like this trick can be used for `Note` as well.

How do we categorize/tag the notes in online Dynamics CRM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all entities in CRM are customizable (or fully customizable), you can see the full detail [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334739.aspx#customizable_entity_properies).

In the case of Notes (Annotation), the properties **CanBeInManyToMany** and **CanBeRelatedEntityInRelationship** are set to false which means that you won't be able to establish a custom entity relationship or create a N:N relationship.

Taking advantage of the fact that you're using CRM Online, is it possible for you to set up the [Sharepoint integration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863709.aspx)? This would allow you to manage your attachments easily (and tag them using the Sharepoint native feature).

Comment: Different question - I'm getting [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ8AM.png) when [importing an updated solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309424.aspx#Anchor_2). Is there any known issue?